# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClassを解決したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### 前提・実現したいこと

ただいま個人アプリでToDoアプリを制作しております。ユーザーモデルとリストモデルを作りそのリストモデルに「何日までにやる」というリストを作ろうとしています。その後タスクモデルを作り、そのリストの中にTodoを作っていく予定です。
フォームヘルパーでdate_selectedフィールドを作り日付を選択できるようにし、その日付をindexページに表示できるようにしたいのですが、うまくいきません。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

[image: エラー画面]
[image: ターミナル]

#### 該当のソースコード

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lists = List.all.includes(:user)
  end

  def new 
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    params[:deadline] = deadline_join
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    if @list.save
      redirect_to lists_path, success: "リストを登録しました。"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:deadline, user_ids: [])
  end

  def deadline_join
    # パラメータ取得
    date = params[:deadline]

    # 年月日別々できたものを結合して新しいDate型変数を作って返す
      Date.new date["deadline(1i)"].to_i,date["deadline(2i)"].to_i,date["deadline(3i)"].to_i
  end
end
```

lists.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
end
```

listのマイグレーションファイル

```
class CreateLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :lists do |t|
      t.date :deadline, null: false
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

#### 試したこと

userのidが取得できていないようなのでアソシエーションができていないのかなと確かめてみましたが、間違いはないように思います。

Comment: エラーメッセージもできれば画像キャプチャではなく、文字として質問に含めてもらうと回答の際に引用がしやすかったり検索に引っ掛かりやすくなるので、より親切かなと思います。

Comment: エラーメッセージに載っているソースコードと質問文に載っているソースコードが異なるようですがどちらが正しいですか？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/280790